# Restyle font-size of axis ticks in plotly

Tags: javascript, html, plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to change the fontsize of x,y,z axis-ticks in a plotly graph based on the value entered by the user, using plotly restyle.

```
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.24.1.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="LabelSizeInput" placeholder="Enter label size" />
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- graph --></div>
</body>

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    tickfont: {
      size: 12 // Set the desired size for x-axis tick values
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    tickfont: {
      size: 12 // Set the desired size for y-axis tick values
    }
  }
};


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

var inputElement = document.getElementById('LabelSizeInput');
inputElement.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var label_size = parseInt(inputElement.value);
  if (!isNaN(label_size)) {
    Plotly.restyle('myDiv', {
      'xaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
      'yaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
    });
  }
});
```

The font-size is not changing when `restlye` is used.
Suggestions on how to fix this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things :

- `Plotly.restyle()` is meant to change attributes in the `data` array. In order to update axes attributes which are part of the layout, use `Plotly.relayout()` (see [Function Reference in JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/)).
- One of the main difference with 3D plots compared to 2D is that the layout objects, including the axes, are in a [*scene*](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/scene/#layout-scene).

```js
Plotly.relayout('myDiv', {
  'scene.xaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
  'scene.yaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
});
```